# Angular 2. @Input since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular, typescript, input, properties, bind

I got a parent component with following template:

```
<ion-content>
  <blocks-banners-slideshow class="contentBlock" [config]="{ zone: 'mobile'}" [config_private]="{ url: 'url'}" [slideOptions]="{ loop: true, pager: true}"></blocks-banners-slideshow>
  <blocks-catalog-category class="contentBlock" [config]="{ parent_id: 0 }" [config_private]="{ url: 'url'}"></blocks-catalog-category>
  <blocks-catalog-topproducts class="contentBlock" [config]="{ filter: { dir: 204}, page: 1, pageSize: 8}" [config_private]="{ url: 'url', showMoreProducts: false, columns: { tablet: 4, phone: 2}}"></blocks-catalog-topproducts>
</ion-content>
```

And then application try to show it tell me:
Unhandled Promise rejection:

Template parse errors:

```
Can't bind to 'config_private' since it isn't a known property of 'blocks-banners-slideshow'.
1. If 'blocks-banners-slideshow' is an Angular component and it has 'config_private' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'blocks-banners-slideshow' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

A child component text:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blocks-banners-slideshow', //Селектор
  templateUrl: '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/banners/blocks/slideshow', //Шаблон
})

export class BannersBlocksSlideShow extends AbstractBlock{
  list: Array<BannerItem>;
  mySlideOptions: any;

  //Входящие данные
  @Input() config: any;
  @Input() config_public: any;
  @Input() slideOptions = {};

 ....
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The component doesn't have a `config_private` property, only `config_public`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can't bind to 'config_private' since it isn't a known property of 'blocks-banners-slideshow'.

Means it can't find `config_private` so there are 3 ways to go about fixing this

1. Add the missing property to the component
2. In the component, change the property from `config_public` to `config_private`
3. In the `.html` change the bound property from `config_private` to `config_public`

**First Option** - Add the missing property to the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blocks-banners-slideshow', //Селектор
  templateUrl: '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/banners/blocks/slideshow', //Шаблон
})

export class BannersBlocksSlideShow extends AbstractBlock{
  list: Array<BannerItem>;
  mySlideOptions: any;

  //Входящие данные
  @Input() config: any;
  @Input() config_public: any;
  @Input() config_private: any; // <--- Add this
  @Input() slideOptions = {};

 ....
}
```

**Second option** - In the component, change the property from `config_public` to `config_private`

```
<ion-content>
  <blocks-banners-slideshow class="contentBlock" [config]="{ zone: 'mobile'}" [config_private]="{ url: 'url'}" [slideOptions]="{ loop: true, pager: true}"></blocks-banners-slideshow>
  <blocks-catalog-category class="contentBlock" [config]="{ parent_id: 0 }" [config_private]="{ url: 'url'}"></blocks-catalog-category>
  <blocks-catalog-topproducts class="contentBlock" [config]="{ filter: { dir: 204}, page: 1, pageSize: 8}" [config_private]="{ url: 'url', showMoreProducts: false, columns: { tablet: 4, phone: 2}}"></blocks-catalog-topproducts>
</ion-content>
```

Since I don't see a `[config_public]="..."` property being bound try changing `config_public` to `config_private` in your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blocks-banners-slideshow', //Селектор
  templateUrl: '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/banners/blocks/slideshow', //Шаблон
})

export class BannersBlocksSlideShow extends AbstractBlock{
  list: Array<BannerItem>;
  mySlideOptions: any;

  //Входящие данные
  @Input() config: any;
  @Input() config_private: any; // <--- Change this
  @Input() slideOptions = {};

 ........
}
```

**Third Option** - In the `.html` change the bound property from `config_private` to `config_public`

Try changing the bound property to `config_public`

```
<ion-content>
  <blocks-banners-slideshow class="contentBlock" [config]="{ zone: 'mobile'}" [config_public]="{ url: 'url'}" [slideOptions]="{ loop: true, pager: true}"></blocks-banners-slideshow>
  <blocks-catalog-category class="contentBlock" [config]="{ parent_id: 0 }" [config_public]="{ url: 'url'}"></blocks-catalog-category>
  <blocks-catalog-topproducts class="contentBlock" [config]="{ filter: { dir: 204}, page: 1, pageSize: 8}" [config_public]="{ url: 'url', showMoreProducts: false, columns: { tablet: 4, phone: 2}}"></blocks-catalog-topproducts>
</ion-content>
```

### Update

Make sure component is declared in the apps module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BannersBlocksSlideShow } from './banners-blocks-slideShow/banners-blocks-slideShow.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        BannersBlocksSlideShow
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes you are right config_public was wrong named. I was renamed it but the error is still here. What it can be?

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting now, after the variable rename

Comment: I found the solution. First it was in wrong named property inside component. Second I haven't declarated it in declarations section

Comment: declaration must be in NgModule

Comment: Correct! Your apps module needs to know what components its using! Good work!

Comment: Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to help out!

Comment: @LoganH Your solution helped me to resolve an issue in my application. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 9):

For me, this error occured because I wrote

```
@Input
```

instead of

```
@Input()
```

before the property.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ionic 2 with lazy loading then you may be forgot to include the declaration of your block in page module. In this case the error will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on Alexander Zakusilo answer a little bit because I think that what he said was my issue, but it didn't immediately click for me...

A great [stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350652/ionic-3-does-each-page-need-its-own-module) about lazy loading with Ionic 3 that has some included links to docs...

Let's say that you have a bunch of components grouped up in a component module.

```
const components = [
  GraphLineComponent,
  GraphDateRangeTabsComponent,
  GraphBarComponent,
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ...components,
  ],
  imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [
    ...components,
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

And you want to use one of those components in an ionic page that you are lazy loading... You need to import your components module into the page module where you want to use the component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GraphPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(GraphPage),
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
})
export class GraphPageModule {}
```

My issue was that I was importing my components module into my bootstrapped app module and expecting it to work. And if you aren't lazy loading, it will, because everything will exist in the app module.